# Could not run JSP project in glassfish server: A full JDK (not just JRE) is required"

Tags: java, glassfish

I have developed an e-commerce application using JSP, Servlet, Javabeans and MySQL. I have followed the Netbeans tutorial for e-commerce development. My application is running fine in Netbeans environment. But when I want to deploy it in Glassfish server (without using Netbeans), it shows an error:

> "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in
>   invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required".

I have installed JDK into my machine and also set the classpath. I have no idea why this error shows. I want to run the application in Glassfish server without using Netbeans. Please suggest me the full steps for this. (I have placed the war file of my project into the autodeploy folder of the server).

Comment: *"I have set the classpath"*. Are you sure you're not mixing "classpath" with "path"? GlassFish never consults the `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable. This badly thought environment variable, which should never have been invented/introduced by the Sun guys, has an entirely different purpose.

Comment: I have set the path environment variable to the path of my Java installation directory. Besides this, should I have to set the Java Home in Glassfish admin console? If so, how do I proceed?

Comment: Now I can see my projects home page on the browser. But whenever I click on any link in my site, it shows an error"The requested resource () is not available." Where is the error? I can run it correctly in NetBeans. The server log shows an warning"WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\MyProject recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]". Please reply soon.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the current problem. That's an entirely different problem. There's an "Ask Question" button on right top which allows you to ask a new question here. And, as an advice, try not being rude by commanding/pressing others. You'll otherwise easily be ignored or downvoted. Just ask the question the smart way and don't whine.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `JAVA_HOME = JAVA_JDK_PATH` and restart the glassfish server

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path it's trying to use for a jdk is in fact a jdk?
Quick googling shows me this error is common with some plugins where it gets confused and points to a JRE instead of a JDK despite the presence of a JDK

Comment: I have no idea about how to set the path variable for the glassfish server. Please provide the right steps.Besides it, Please provide the correct steps to run my project on glassfish server without running it from Netbeans.

Comment: Now I can see my projects home page on the browser. But whenever I click on any link in my site, it shows an error"The requested resource () is not available." Where is the error? I can run it correctly in NetBeans. The server log shows an warning"WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.com.sun.‌​enterprise.deploy.shared|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8031: Ignoring WEB-INF/ because the containing archive C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\MyProject recorded it as a pre-existing stale file|#]". Please reply soon.

Comment: I am not personally farmiliar with glassfish, try seeing if they have an irc channel and ask there, or google the archive file is recorded as a pre-existing stale file

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions offered here and on other posts, including setting the path to the jdk in asenv.conf. The ONLY thing that worked for me was going to the glassfish admin console Configurations/server-config/JVM Settings and changing Java Home from ${com.sun.aas.javaRoot} to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java.exe. Truly, Glassfish is a piece of crap!

Answer (score 0):

Locate and edit this file: glassfish/config/asenv.bat

Add this entry: AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0   (location of your JDK)

Save this and restart glassfish.

Hope this helps.